# Trying To Retrieve Name Instead of Primary Key, But Django Rest Framework complains of Value Error. If I try to fix it, I got other errors too

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Models:

```
  def upload_to(instance, filename):
      return 'images/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

  class StreamPlatform(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      about = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
      website = models.URLField(max_length=2500)
  
      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

  class WatchList(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to=upload_to, default='images/default.jpg')
      storyline = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
      platform = models.ForeignKey(StreamPlatform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='watchlist')
      active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      avg_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
      number_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  
      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

My Serializers:

```
class WatchListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    platform = serializers.CharField(source='platform.name')
    class Meta:
        model = WatchList
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'avg_rating': {'read_only': True}, 'number_rating': {'read_only': True}}
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return WatchList.objects.create(**validated_data)

class StreamPlatformSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    watchlist = WatchListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StreamPlatform
        fields = '__all__'
```

My View:

```
class WatchListAV(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AdminOrReadOnly]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    queryset = WatchList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WatchListSerializer
    pagination_class = WatchListLimitOffsetPagination
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['title', 'platform__name']
    ordering_fields = ['avg_rating']
```

The issue I got is that Django Rest Framework complains in PostMan that:

> ValueError at /watch/list/ Cannot assign "{'name': '8'}":
> "WatchList.platform" must be a "StreamPlatform" instance.

When I try to fix it like this in the WatchListSerializer:

```
platform = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = StreamPlatform.objects.all(), source='platform.name',)
```

I got a new error instead:

> ValueError at /watch/list/ Cannot assign "{'name': <StreamPlatform:
> Blah>}": "WatchList.platform" must be a "StreamPlatform" instance.

When I commented out the error-prone code bits, I got the correct Response, just not the Response I'm hoping for.

```
{
    "id": 26,
    "title": "Awesome Show Blah Blah",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/default.jpg",
    "storyline": "Any blah...",
    "active": true,
    "avg_rating": 0.0,
    "number_rating": 0,
    "created": "2022-05-12T17:04:04.151048Z",
    "platform": 8
}
```

I'm hoping for the "platform": 8 to be shown in name like "platform": Blah.  So how do you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

```
class WatchListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    platform = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=StreamPlatform.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
    class Meta:
        model = WatchList
        fields = ['platform', 'all_other_fields']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'avg_rating': {'read_only': True}, 
            'number_rating': {'read_only': True}
        }
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return WatchList.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: I got this error now if I use SlugRelatedField:  IntegrityError at /watch/list/
NOT NULL constraint failed: watchlist_app_watchlist.platform_id.  Does this mean I have to make changes to my model?  Or does this mean something has gone wrong and the object was returned as none?

Comment: Now, if I try it like this: platform = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset = StreamPlatform.objects.all(), source='platform.name', slug_field='name', allow_null=True), I got this from PostMan: {"platform":["Object with name=8 does not exist."]}.  So, I'm even more confused now.

Comment: Hello @VinhNguyen you've defined fields `__all__` since you're overriding **platform** field you've to specify inside your fields list like this `fields = ["platform", ..all other fields]` check I've edited my answer

Comment: Now I got this error after stopped using __all__ for fields and specifically specify each field including platform.  IntegrityError at /watch/list/
NOT NULL constraint failed: watchlist_app_watchlist.platform_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/watch/list/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: watchlist_app_watchlist.platform_id

Comment: Hello @VinhNguyen if you're trying to get data then you've to use **GET** and if you're trying to create then you've to use **POST** and while creating you've to pass *request.body* inside you postman. While creating body you've to provide platform_id in body.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got it right when using PostMan.  It's just the error keeps on appearing.  Check out [link]https://www.flickr.com/photos/blogmyway/52072897551/in/dateposted-public/ to see the image of my PostMan and its issues.

Comment: Hello @VinhNguyen check I've edited my answer

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:  "Object with name=9 does not exist." in PostMan.  Come to think of this, I wonder if there is a solution to this.  I can't find a solution on the web anywhere for my situation.  Nothing seems to work.